# Array List Null Pointer Exception - Android

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I am trying to create an application which retrieves the users favourite book quote however I am stuck on how to display this information back to the user. I created an ArrayList which will store all the information. However when displaying this information, I keep getting the error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException

when it tries to execute the code

```
temp[i] = new HashMap<String,String>();
```

This class is shown below:

```
public class FavouriteQuotesActivity extends ListActivity {

    static final ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

    private void getFavorites() {
        DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);

        String favorites [] = myDbHelper.getFavourites();

        if(list.size() > 0)
        {
            list.removeAll(list);
        }

        for(int i = 0;i < favorites.length; i++)
        {
            String quotes = favorites[i];
            String[] quoteArray = quotes.split(":");
            HashMap<String,String> temp[] = null; 

            temp[i] = new HashMap<String,String>();
            temp[i].put("Author",(quoteArray[2]));
            temp[i].put("Quote",(quoteArray[4]));
            list.add(temp[i]);

        }


    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at this code:

```
HashMap<String,String> temp[] = null; 
temp[i] = new HashMap<String,String>();
```

You've *just assigned* a null value to the `temp` variable (which would more typically have a declaration of `HashMap<String, String>[] temp`) - so of course you'll get a `NullPointerException` when you then try to access `temp[i]` on the very next statement.

It's not clear why you're using an array at all in that code - why aren't you just using:

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("Author", quoteArray[2]);
map.put("Quote", quoteArray[4]);
list.add(map);
```

Additionally it's unclear why you're using a map at all here, given that it will always have the same two keys. Why not create a `Quote` class with name and author properties? Also, using a static variable here seems like a bad idea - why doesn't `getFavorites` create a new list on each invocation, and return it at the end of the method?

Comment: The problem is that `temp` should not even be an array in the first place.

Comment: @Tudor: Hence the second part of my answer...  it's not clear that a map is really needed either.

Comment: @user983965: But do you *understand* why the change was needed? Have you considered the questions in the final paragraph?

Answer (score 3):

`temp` doesn't point to an array. You are setting it to `null`.

You declared the variable temp as an array (by writing `HashMap temp[]`).

Without being it an actual array, you can't set any elements.

Comment: It *is* initialized - with the null value. That's a perfectly valid initial value... it's just you can't then dereference it...

Comment: I'd still bicker with the details in the second part: `temp` is a variable. Its value is either null, or a reference to an array. When the value is null, you can't set any elements.

Comment: @Jon: Indeed. Is there a nice name for what I meant to wrote. Apparently not "initialised". A word that says it is a null pointer?

Comment: How about "it's being initialized with a value of null"? After all, that's what you really mean :)

Comment: That sounds good. And what do you say about `Object o = new Object(); o = null;`? In what state is `o` now? Because, it was initialised to `new Object()`, but now, it is null.

Comment: It has a value of `null`, it's as simple as that. The variable is *definitely assigned* (so code is able to read the value) - it's just that the value is null. It was previously assigned a non-null reference, and the second assignment changes the value to a null reference.

Comment: Ok thanks, looks like there no real way to say it using one adjective. (You've got my +1 :))

Answer (score 3):

You are declaring and using `temp` wrong. You don't need an array of `HashMap`, just a single `HashMap`, since `list` is an `ArrayList<HashMap>`:

```
HashMap<String,String> temp = new HashMap<String,String>();
temp.put("Author",(quoteArray[2]));
temp.put("Quote",(quoteArray[4]));
list.add(temp);
```